# Tidyr unite with more than one separator

Tags: r, tidyr

Is there a possibility to use unite from tidyr but modify different separators?

I have:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
col1  col2     col3  col4
John  middle   no    Switzerland
Sue   middle   yes   Norway
Nancy low      yes   Germany
Sid   high     no    Germany", header=T)


df<-unite(df1, col1, col2, col3, col4, sep=";", col="var")

head(df)
var
John;middle;no;Switzerland
Sue;middle;yes;Norway
Nanc;low;yes;Germany
Sid;high;no;Germany
```

This is the desired output:

```
head(df)
var
p_John;x_middle;d_no;c_Switzerland
p_Sue;x_middle;d_yes;c_Norway
p_Nanc;x_low;d_yes;c_Germany
p_Sid;x_high;d_no;c_Germany
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your desired output has the same separator, you've just prepended letter + underscore to each value.

Comment: so, the only way I could do it is adding them per a column, then uniting? 
No possibility that I treat this as a different separators?

Comment: I can't find any way to pass in more than one `sep` argument, so it doesn't look like it. Even if there were a way, you would still have to add the `p_` at the beginning using some other method. Probably better to just add the prefixes and then `unite`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've done, just wondered if I could add different separators, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can, but it's straightforward to create a function which does the same thing:

```
library(tidyverse)

unite_with_seps <- function(df, name, cols, seps) {
  df <- unite(df, !!name, all_of(cols), sep = "_")
  pattern <- paste(rep("([\\w]+)", length(cols)), collapse = "_") # this is a regex which will turn every group of letters surrounded by an underscore into a group 
  replacement <- map_chr(seq_along(seps), ~paste0(seps[.x], "\\", .x)) %>% paste0(collapse = ";") # this turns the desired output into a replacement pattern
  mutate(df, !!name := str_replace_all(!!sym(name), pattern, replacement))
}

unite_with_seps(df1, "var", c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"), c("p_", "x_", "d_", "c_"))

                                 var
1 p_John;x_middle;d_no;c_Switzerland
2      p_Sue;x_middle;d_yes;c_Norway
3      p_Nancy;x_low;d_yes;c_Germany
4        p_Sid;x_high;d_no;c_Germany
```

If it's at all unclear, run `debug(unite_with_seps)` and then run the function again, and go through it step by step, seeing what the variables become.